# TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined in Jest testing

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I'm getting this error while tring to render the class. I didn't get any errors when I rendered App js which has this page as a part of it. I have used Jest JS for testing. Can someone please help me out?

//Page1.js

```
<CustomRadioGroup
                label="What would you like to use the loan for?"
                name="loan"
                value={this.props.formikProps.values.loan}
                type="radio"
                options={[
                  "abc",
                  "def",
                  "ghi"
                ]}
              />
```

//Page1.test.js

```
it("render without crashing", () => {
    const {debug} = render(<Page1/>)
    debug();
})
```

Error:

```
  26 |                 label="What would you like to use the loan for?"
  27 |                 name="loan"
> 28 |                 value={this.props.formikProps.values.loan}
     |                                               ^
```

Comment: You render the component without any props, where did you expect formikProps to come from?

Comment: I realized that a bit later. Thanks